# Cefsharp crashes while running some scripts. C#

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, cefsharp.offscreen

I use cefsharp to execute some JavaScript commands in browser environment (console) inside a loop.

For example, When I want to run a command like `Goog_AdSense_` (related to the "Google AdSense" app), cefsharp crashes and the rest of the loop will not be executed.

I know cefsharp uses `IRequestHandler` interface to call `OnRenderProcessTerminated` method to display an error, but wondering how to proceed from here!

How to perform and run the rest of the loop?

```
class InternalBrowser
{
    void CheckJS(AppSignature app, InternalBrowser browser, Scripts scripts)
    {
        foreach (var script in scripts)
            browser.RunScript(script);
    }

    public bool RunScript(string script, InternalBrowser browser)
    {
        Task<JavascriptResponse> task = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
        task.Wait();

        bool result = task.Result.Success && (task.Result.Result != null);

        return result;
    }
}


class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler
{
    public void OnRenderViewReady(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
    }

    public bool OnProtocolExecution(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string url)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
    {

    }

    public void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
    {
        //Here is the error display
    }
    public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isRedirect)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, ref string newUrl)
    {
    }

    public bool OnResourceResponse(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {
        var t = response.ResponseHeaders;
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnQuotaRequest(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, long newSize, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        return CefReturnValue.Continue;
    }

    public bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnOpenUrlFromTab(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

An example in the google chrome console:

[image: An example in the google chrome console]

Comment: Firstly calling Wait on the result of EvaluateScriptAsync is not recommended or supported,  it returns a Task you must await or use ContinueWith. A JavaScript error shouldn't crash the render process under normal circumstances. What CefTerminationStatus are you seeing? Please include the version you are using whenever asking a question.

Comment: @amaitland CefSharp.CefTerminationStatus.ProcessCrashed

Comment: @amaitland public async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> RunScript(string script, InternalBrowser browser)
{
    var task = await Task.Run(() => browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script));

    bool result = task.Success && (task.Result != null);
    string str = (result) ? task.Result.ToString() : string.Empty;
    return new Tuple<bool, string>(result, str);
}  Changes have been made but there is  problem

Comment: my cefsharp version is 45.0.0.0